# Closed Form for Finite Sum: Product of two Similar Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

I need to find a closed form expression in terms of $c$, $n$, $x$ and $y$ for

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n}\rho^{c-j}\frac{x^j}{j!}\frac{y^{c-2j}}{\left(c-2j\right)!}
$$

where $c$ and $\rho$ are just constants. I just can't spot the insight, not really experienced with finding closed forms for finite sums...perhaps this series is a particular type of finite series (not geometric, but maybe something else?).....

You can use the fact that $c=2n$ (though I doubt this helps).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\rho^{2n-k}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}\frac{y^{2n-2k}}{\left(2n-2k!\right)}=\left(y\rho\right)^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!\left(2n-2k\right)!}\left(\frac{x}{y^{2}\rho}\right)^{k}=$$ $$=\frac{\left(y\rho\right)^{2n}}{\left(2n\right)!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{k!\left(2n-2k\right)!}\left(\frac{x}{y^{2}\rho}\right)^{k}=$$ $$=\frac{\left(y\rho\right)^{2n}}{2n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\left(2n\right)\left(2n-2\right)\cdots\left(2n-2k+2\right)\left(2n-1\right)\cdots\left(2n-2k+1\right)}{k!}\left(\frac{x}{y^{2}\rho}\right)^{k}=$$
 $$=\frac{\left(y\rho\right)^{2n}}{2n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{2^{2k}\left(n\left(n-1\right)\cdots\left(n-\left(k-1\right)\right)\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdots\left(n-\frac{1}{2}-\left(k-1\right)\right)\right)}{k!}\left(\frac{y^{2}\rho}{x}\right)^{-k}=\frac{\left(y\rho\right)^{2n}}{2n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n\left(n-1\right)\cdots\left(n-\left(k-1\right)\right)\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdots\left(n-\frac{1}{2}-\left(k-1\right)\right)}{k!}\left(\frac{y^{2}\rho}{4x}\right)^{-k}=$$ $$=\frac{\left(y\rho\right)^{2n}}{2n!}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{n\left(n-1\right)\cdots\left(n-\left(k-1\right)\right)\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdots\left(n-\frac{1}{2}-\left(k-1\right)\right)}{k!}\left(\frac{y^{2}\rho}{4x}\right)^{-k}$$
 Recalling that the falling factorial is $$\left(a\right)_{k}=a\left(a-1\right)\cdots\left(a-\left(k-1\right)\right)$$
 and its relation wih the Pochhammer symbol $\left(*\right)^{\left(k\right)}$
  (or rising factorial)$$\left(a\right)_{k}=\left(-1\right)^{k}\left(-a\right)^{\left(k\right)}\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$
 the sum is$$\frac{\left(y\rho\right)^{2n}}{2n!}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(n\right)_{k}\left(n+\frac{1}{2}-1\right)_{k}}{k!}\left(\frac{y^{2}\rho}{4x}\right)^{-k}=\frac{\left(y\rho\right)^{2n}}{2n!}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-n\right)^{\left(k\right)}\left(-n-\frac{1}{2}+1\right)^{\left(k\right)}}{k!}\left(\frac{y^{2}\rho}{4x}\right)^{-k}=\frac{\left(-4x\rho\right)}{2n!}^{n}\left(-\frac{y^{2}\rho}{4x}\right)^{n} {}_2F_0\left(-n,1-n-\frac{1}{2};;\left(\frac{y^{2}\rho}{4x}\right)^{-1}\right)=\frac{\left(-4x\rho\right)}{2n!}^{n}U\left(-n,\frac{1}{2},-\frac{y^{2}\rho}{4x}\right)$$
 where $_qF_p\left(a_{1},\dots,a_{p};b_{1},\dots,b_{q};x\right)$
  is the generalized hypergeometric function and $U\left(a,b,z\right)$
  is the confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind.

Comment: How have you done the final sum, just before the appearance of $_2 F_0$?

Comment: There was a typo, thank you. Using $(1)$ you can pull out $(-1)^{k}$ from each rising factorial, but $(-1)^{k}(-1)^{k}=(-1)^{2k}=1.$

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question using Mathematica, the closed form appears to be

$$
\frac{2^{c-1} (\rho y)^{c} (-\rho y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{c}{2}}}{x^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{c}{2}}c!}U(\frac{1-c}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{-\rho y^2}{4x})
$$

using $c=2n$, where $U(a,b,c)$ is the confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind.

Comment: I imagine this is equivalent to Marco's answer.

Comment: I assume, as you said, $c=2n$. Using Wolfram the result is the same of mine. There is some problem when I try to copy the link here, but you can prove by yourself.

Comment: Genuine thanks Marco. Any advice on where to start on these kinds of problems?

Comment: This is the right place to start. Look the proofs of the other person and try to understand every passage of their argument ;)